# Coordinates of the ends of the right diagonal from a point in a grid

Tags: matrices, geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose you have an n x n grid and an arbitrary point (x,y) on that grid.

[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPQu.png)

How could you write the coordinates of the two points (?,?) in figure 1 **in terms of x, y, and n**.

Comment: Need more details

Comment: Do you already have the slope of the line? You basically have a line and a point, so you can use the point-slope equation to find the equation of the line.

Comment: The slope is 1, but I don't need the equation of the line. I need only the coordinates of the two points. The left point can either be on the bottom side or the left side and the right point can either be on the top or on the right side, so finding intercepts is not the solution.